# Xtext: Export model as XMI/XML

Tags: java, xml, xtext, xmi

I have defined a DSL with Xtext. Let's say it looks like this:

```
Model:
    components+=Component*
;

Component:
    House | Car
;

House:
    'House' name=ID
    ('height' hubRadius=DOUBLE)? &
    ('width' hubRadius=DOUBLE)?
    'end' 'House'
;

Car:
    'Car' name=ID
    ('maxSpeed' hubRadius=INT)? &
    ('brand' hubRadius=STRING)?
    'end' 'Car'
;
```

In the generated Eclipse IDE, which is based on my DSL, I implemented a model. Let's say it looks like the following:

```
House MyHouse
    height 102.5
    width 30.56
end House

Car MyCar
    maxSpeed 190
    brand "mercedes"
end Car
```

I now would like to export that model as an XMI or XML file.

The reason I want to do this is, that I have another workflow, which allows me to change the model parameters on the fly, using an XMI/XML file. So instead of redefining my model, I can just pass the XML/XMI file to the workflow, which does this automatically.

Short example: The DSL allows defining the components `House` and `Car`. The `House` allows the parameters `width` and `height`, the `Car` allows the parameters `maxSpeed` and `brand` (see grammar above).

So in my workflow I was talking about, the parameters will be changed with different values. For example the generated XML I am looking for would look like this:

```
<model>
    <component name='House'>
        <param name='height'>102.5</param>
        <param name='width'>30.56</param>
    </component>
    <component name='Car'>
        <param name='maxSpeed'>190</param>
        <param name='brand'>mercedes</param>
    </component>
</model>
```

How can I export my model as XMI/XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finaly found a solution. The following code exports an *.xmi file like requested in my opening post:

```
private void exportXMI(String absuloteTargetFolderPath) {
    // change MyLanguage with your language name
    Injector injector = new MyLanguageStandaloneSetup()
            .createInjectorAndDoEMFRegistration();
    XtextResourceSet resourceSet = injector
            .getInstance(XtextResourceSet.class);

    // .ext ist the extension of the model file
    String inputURI = "file:///" + absuloteTargetFolderPath + "/MyFile.ext";
    String outputURI = "file:///" + absuloteTargetFolderPath + "/MyFile.xmi";
    URI uri = URI.createURI(inputURI);
    Resource xtextResource = resourceSet.getResource(uri, true);

    EcoreUtil.resolveAll(xtextResource);

    Resource xmiResource = resourceSet
            .createResource(URI.createURI(outputURI));
    xmiResource.getContents().add(xtextResource.getContents().get(0));
    try {
        xmiResource.save(null);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a comment to John's answer:
Inside Eclipse IDE never use MyLanguageStandaloneSetup, the instance of an injector MUST be accessed via an Activator of a UI plugin: MyLanguageActivator.getInstance().getInjector(MyLanguageActivator.COM_MYCOMPANY_MYLANGUAGE).

Calling of MyLanguageStandaloneSetup.createInjectorAndDoEMFRegistration will create a new instance of an Injector that is different from used by Eclipse. Also it can break the state of EMF registries.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment! Although I am importing MyLanguageActivator successfully, I get an `NoClassDefFoundError` during runtime. Do you know why this happens?

Comment: How do you run exporting? If inside Eclipse when you should put your code in UI plugin to be able to access an activator. If outside you can put it in a langauge project and use a standalone setup.